# Angular 5 terminate a function after navigation

Tags: javascript, angular

I work with Angular 5. I am using a function carousel in ngOnInit(). The problem is when I clicked to navigate to other page, in console shows me the below message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at carousel (home-gr.component.ts:70)
```

My code in my component:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    let slideIndex = 0; 

    function carousel() {
        let i;
        let x = <HTMLElement[]><any>document.getElementsByClassName("titleweb");
        let y = <HTMLElement[]><any>document.getElementsByClassName("devimages");
        let z = <HTMLElement[]><any>document.getElementsByClassName("devlogoimages");
        let dx = <HTMLElement[]><any>document.getElementsByClassName("titlewebdes");
        let dy = <HTMLElement[]><any>document.getElementsByClassName("photodesignclass");
        let dz = <HTMLElement[]><any>document.getElementsByClassName("deslogoimages");

        for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(x).length; i++) {
          x[i].style.backgroundColor = "black";
          x[i].style.color = "white";
          dx[i].style.backgroundColor = "black";
          dx[i].style.color = "white";
          y[i].style.opacity = "0";
          z[i].style.opacity = "0";
          dy[i].style.opacity = "0";
          dz[i].style.opacity = "0";
        }
        slideIndex++;
        if (slideIndex > Object.keys(x).length) {slideIndex = 1} 
        x[slideIndex-1].style.backgroundColor = "#ff6600";
        x[slideIndex-1].style.color = "black";
        dx[slideIndex-1].style.backgroundColor = "#ff6600";
        dx[slideIndex-1].style.color = "black";
        y[slideIndex-1].style.opacity = "1";
        z[slideIndex-1].style.opacity = "1";
        dy[slideIndex-1].style.opacity = "1";
        dz[slideIndex-1].style.opacity = "1";
        setTimeout(carousel, 3000); 
    }
    carousel();
  }
```

Maybe I could in ngOnDestroy() to destroy carousel function but I don't know how. If you need more details please ask me to reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call [clearTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) for canceling the setTimeout instance on `ngOnDestroy`.

```
private carouselTimeoutVar : any;

ngOnInit() {
    this.carouselTimeoutVar = setTimeout(carousel, 3000);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    clearTimeout(this.carouselTimeoutVar);
}
```

Comment: There is a problem Cannot set property 'carouselTimeoutVar' of undefined and after that it shows me the previous message again Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Comment: Instead of using function carousel, use arrow functions to obtain the outside scope's this. `let carousel = () => {.....}` instead of `function carousel(){...}`